# Wrap a VueJs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2

I'm using a third party datepicker component. I created a wrapper for this component so I can set some defaults that fit my application. However, I'm having problems passing the model. How can I ensure the two-way binding for my model? When I use the third party component directly, everything works.

**my-page.vue**

`<my-datepicker v-model="from"></my-datepicker>`

**my-datepicker.vue**

```js
<template>
  <thirdparty-datepicker>
    :value="value"
  </thirdparty-datepicker>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        value: String
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Based on the input from Bert I managed to get it to work. Every time the date changed on the third party component an `input` event was thrown. All there was to do was hookup to that event and re-emit it.

```
<template>
  <thirdparty-datepicker>
    :value="value"
    v-on:input="change"
  </thirdparty-datepicker>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        value: String
      }
    },
    methods: {
      change (newValue) {
        this.$emit('input', newValue)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to give that property a different name than "value"? Maybe that's messing up things.

Comment: Value is one of the properties the datepicker has. I'm basicly creating a ono to one map of the properties of the third party datepicker and my wrapper. If I understand correctly, value is name of the property that matches when I do `v-model="from"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to support `v-model` on your custom component you have to [accept a value parameter and emit an `input` event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) (though that can be customized; see the link for details). Your code is only doing part of that. How you implement that is going to depend on how the third party component works.

Let's say that the third party component emitted a `change` event. If it did, then you would emit `input` when the third party component emitted `change`.

```
<template>
  <thirdparty-datepicker :value="value" @change="onChange">    
  </thirdparty-datepicker>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        value: String
      }
    },
    methods:{
      onChange(newValue){
        this.$emit('input', newValue)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've read something like this in the docs but I could really get my head around it. Your explanation did the trick. Thanks!